# What Nikon lens is this? What kind of UV-pass beam splitter is this?

Tags: lens, nikon, optics, uv, nature

A detective challenge for this wonderful community of experts:
I am working on a science museum exhibit about the different ways animals can see light. I am trying to reverse engineer the [incredible beam-splitting camera rig used in the production of  David Attenborough's 'Life in Color'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwexvE91lRI&t=119s) It seems like two Sony A7s at 90 degrees with a beam splitter that passes UV only and reflects full spectrum light.
Sadly for this purpose, most modern lenses have uv-blocking coatings on many elements, making UV videography difficult.

1. Is anyone able to recognize this lens pair? It looks like a older Nikkor prime lens, but I cannot tell more from this shot.
2. Is anyone able to ascertain what the specs of the filter/beam splitter is? I assume it is UV-bandpass, but I am far from an expert.

[image: two cameras at 90degrees to each other pointed at a piece of dark glass. Lens says Nikon and the aperture ring and autofocus switch are visible, as well as part of the dof window/focus guide]

Comment: I understood that cameras had UV filters over their sensors, but not that lens coatings had UV filtering properties. I mean, screw-on UV filters exist(ed) for a reason, right?

Comment: I have heard that uv-passing lenses are hard to find in modern times from talking to experts at https://www.lifepixel.com/. There are special Quartz-glass lenses that pass UV well, but they are very costly. I am far from an expert, and I think it may depend on what type of UV one is trying to pass. I have also heard that UV filters do nothing on modern cameras. https://petapixel.com/2020/06/04/why-uv-filters-are-basically-useless-on-modern-cameras/

Comment: UV is a pretty wide range of wavelengths. What portion of the UV part of the spectrum are you interested in capturing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can be seen on the one on right looks exactly like a Nikon 60mm macro lens.  If you can see the other side of the lens, it should say AF Micro Nikkor, 60mm. It dates from about 1989.  There is a newer 60mm AF-S version available now.

Comment: Thank you very much!